# how to use gcc to preprocess header only for #ifdef, not for #include and #defines

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, cmock, c-header

I have to preprocess a header, during this I want to only process the header for #ifdef, #if defined sections, other sections like Macro expansion and #include sections should not be expanded or checked. how to get this? I need to pass this output file to another software like cmock to create a mock file and then use it for compilation. but the problem I am facing is if I use gcc -E it generates a file where all #includes are expanded, Macros expanded along with #if defines.
any help would be appreciated

for example:

```
#include <stdint.h>   //i don't want to pre-process this line

#if defined (__MACRO_A__)  //i want to pre-process this line
    void funcA(void);
#else
    void funcB(void);
#endif
```

I want the output file to have only funcB prototype. I have not defined **MACRO_A**, so if I preprocess header only funcB is getting included, but all the #includes are getting expanded, which I don't want.

Comment: `I tried gcc -E option but it is not what I want` Why is it not what you want? The line `#if define __MACRO_A__` is invalid, an error `error: missing binary operator before token "__MACRO_A__"`. It's `define<<d>>` not `define`.

Comment: Do not define __MACRO_A__

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `i don't want to pre-process this line` So remove the line. Either manually or with some tool. `sed '/#include/d'`

Comment: If you do not need to compile the original header, you could write it in a different macro language such as **m4**.

Comment: I found a duplicate, containing various more or less ideal solutions, including a flavour of the `grep` answer posted here.

Comment: Some Unix distributions include an `unifdef` command that removes preprocessor conditionals.

Comment: I finally used http://coan2.sourceforge.net/index.php

Answer (score 1):

> but all the #includes are getting expanded, which I don't want.

So remove them from the file.

```
grep -v '#include' inputfile.c | gcc -E -xc -
```

The regex above can possibly be better.